# odd query when php accessing data from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, double

### Preface

After i executed the query through mysql_query() in php

> "update trade set amount=amount-100 where id=123"

If the previous value of amount was 101,after minus 100，the value is supposed to be 1.
But i checked the data in different ways:

### 1. Directly query in mysql:

**it returns with 0.780009989**(some figure like this,the "0.78" part is actual,after that is just a sample from me,i can't remember exatcly,but i think it doesn't matter)

### 2.Using php:

while using mysql_fetch_object() in php,**it still returns the correct answer of "1"**.

### Test

I've run a test of execute the query 100 times in a loop,**but the "error" does not always occur,just sometimes**.

### Question:

Is it possibly casued by undefined length and decimal length of the "amount" cloumn?
Why php funciton can get it correctly?
Pls tell me whether something went wrong there.

### The detail info of the table and the column as below:

> CREATE TABLE `trade`（ 
>   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
>   `amount`double NOT NULL, 
>   PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ）
>   ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=123 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is caused by the `double` type of amount field, and if you need precision use `DECIMAL`. Change the type and see if you get what you want:

```
ALTER TABLE trade MODIFY amount DECIMAL(10,2);
```

That will store 10 digit numbers (8 before decimal point and 2 after). Change this to reflect the data you will store in your DB.

Comment: Thanks @pajaja i will try this.But i'd like to know "why",would you pls go further：why php can retrieve it correctly?why mysql stored wrong without a definition of length(decimal length)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 update trade set amount=CAST(amount AS SIGNED)-100 where id=123;
```

Ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast